# Genius siblings help build spaceships to escape a dying Earth

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of this book, which was maybe written in the early 90's.

It's about:

- A boy and a girl that when they were babies their parents end up at this facility while traveling.
- They were given some unknown DNA or something in liquid form.
- As they grew older, somehow their parents settle either in Kansas or Oklahoma.
- They grow up to be very smart.

  - Their parents realize this, and somehow the government finds them
- The kids end up helping to build these massive spaceships

  - even discovering how to have unlimited oxygen and power on these ships.
- The space ships are for humans to escape the Earth, as it's going to be destroyed.

It's a small book, and I picked it up at a yard sale in a box of books. I read it once and for some odd reason it's been stuck in my head.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!